# Returning a value object to flex from java which contains two array of strings as it's properties

Tags: java, apache-flex, object, return

I amusing Flex for front end building. I have one doubt regarding sending two array of strings from java to flex.

How can I do that?

For example I have a value object defined like below.

```
class Test
{
    String value1[]={"1","2","3"};
    String value2[]={"narendra","mani","suresh","kane"};

    //Getter and setters goes here
 }
```

Can any one help me on this?

Thanks,

Narendra

Answer (score 1):

This is really a matter of how do you want Flex to communicate with your Java layer, I think the closest to a turn key solution to this is using the BlazeDS jar on the server to do the ActionScript Message Format conversion between Java DTOs and Actionscript DTOs, basically how it works is you code up the Java side then you can have it generate the Java equivalent DTOs that will be tagged with Metadata so when the Java objects are serialized and sent across the wire the client has them as typed objects.

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS

Alternatively you could expose the data as XML using a JSP to generate the XML then just using an HTTPService call to the JSP to get the XML data then since AS3 makes use of E4X parsing the XML into AS3 objects is very easy, lots of examples of doing this just search for e4x AS3 for examples.

Hope this helps,

Shaun